# Интересный вопрос о слове "значит"

Tags: вводные-слова

Интересный вопрос был задан **на другом ресурсе.** Я уже собиралась на него ответить, но потом передумала. Захотелось услышать **ваше мнение**, тем более что нужно было не только записать правильно, но и объяснить. И вот объяснение уже не показалось мне **простым и однозначным...**

Нужна ли запятая после "значит" в предложениях:

***Значит**(,) так!*

***Значит**(,) так, объясняю в десятый раз.*

***Значит**(,) так, приятель.*

Спасибо.

Comment: Вот умора! Уже много раз произнёс "та-та-та", а сколько ещё произнесу? "Почём зря" тоже зацепил.

Comment: Да,  и число вариантов почему-то все время увеличивается... Наверное, это влияние магнитной бури. Да еще 13-е число сегодня... https://dzen.ru/a/ZK8b87gAIEEaITgs

Comment: @Sharon Похоже, что *другой ресурс* — это "Большой вопрос". Нет?  (http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4236878-znachit-tak-nuzhna-li-zapjataja.html)

Comment: Да, Римма, это тема из "Большого вопроса", я иногда туда заглядываю.  Спасибо за комментарий, я даже примерно вспомнила, какой ответ собиралась там дать. Но там народ не особо креативный, в основном мыслят по стандарту. Сегодня, кстати, тоже 13-е число, странное совпадение))

Answer (score 0):

**Вместо вступления**

Для чего задаются такие вопросы?  Ведь всем ж понятен однозначный ответ:  *«Да, **я уверен** практически **на все сто процентов,** что во всех приведённых случаях ставятся запятые. Потому что это вводное слово.*

Думаю, что такие вопросы нужны, чтобы  не мыслить следующим образом: *так происходит **часто**, а значит, происходит **всегда**.* Это **неверная логика**, и исключения доказывают это.

А еще эти вопросы нужны, чтобы лучше знать тему и лишний раз заглянуть **[в Справочник по пунктуации:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220)**

! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения **(сказуемого).** «Корнет, что всё это значит?» – шепотом спросил командир полка. Б. Окуджава, Путешествие дилетантов.

Но ведь там: ***Что** все это значит*?   А здесь: *значит **так*** (значит **вот что**). В разговорном стиле фраза должна подходить **к ситуации** – вот в чем мне видится решение задачи. И это именно **разговорный** стиль и **конкретная** ситуация! Не надо искать там правильный синтаксис **книжной** речи.

Проверка **подстановкой** — это всего лишь проверка **значения** слова (как сказуемого), но другая фраза в структуру конкретного предложения может не вписываться.

Но вот **комментарий:** *Сделайте, чтобы подставлялось (вы с таким же успехом можете написать, что оно слово "слон" заменяет)! Вы так не сможете сделать, потому что это неверно.*

И еще **интересная логика**: *Неверно. Отсутствие лайков подтверждает.*

**ОТВЕТ**

Вопрос кочующий,  в той или иной редакции он повторяется на разных ресурсах.  Так что **пора дать ответ**))

Этот вопрос скорее не на правило, а на понимание **оттенков смысла**: вводное слово «значит» (выражение недовольства) или глагол «значит/означает + местоимение «так» (пояснение).

**Пример 1.** Значит(,) так!

***Значит, так!*** Выражение недовольства, восклицание, только вводное слово.

**Пример 2.** Значит(,) так, объясняю в десятый раз.

Здесь возможны варианты.

1. ***Значит, так, объясняю в десятый раз.*** Вводное слово, выражение недовольства.

Возможный диалог:  *— Ничего не понял!  —  Очень непонятливый? Значит, так, объясняю в десятый раз.*

2. ***Значит так, объясняю в десятый раз.*** Пояснение (значит так).

Возможный диалог:  — Я все уже объяснил. —  Но я не совсем понял, что это **значит…** — **Значит** так, объясняю в десятый раз.

Слово "значит" в **разговорном** стиле заменяет фразу "это значит вот что".

**Пример 3.** Значит(,) так, приятель.

Здесь возможны варианты.

1. ***Значит, так, приятель.***  Вводное слово, выражение недовольства.

Возможный диалог:  — Работаю не хуже других, почему вы только мне делаете замечание? — Значит, так, приятель. Что ты сегодня сделал за целый день?

2. ***Значит так, приятель.***  Пояснение (значит так) с оттенком недовольства.

Возможный диалог:  Работать надо быстрее! — Что значит «надо», куда еще быстрее? — Значит так, приятель. Что ты сегодня сделал за целый день?

**О произношении**

Основным ориентиром при решении задач является **семантика**, именно смысл задает интонацию (разное произношение) и грамматику. Поэтому удобно **такое решение:** (1) Предварительная проверка интонации на наличие вариантов. (2) Семантический и грамматический анализ возможных вариантов. (3)  Окончательная проверка интонации для выбранного варианта.

**[Вопрос](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/233942339)**

***Значит(,) так.*** Нужна ли запятая после "значит"?
В значении: Значит так: пойдешь в направлении парка. Значит так: смотри, что я делаю и повторяй за мной.

Comment: Не знаю, можно конечно запятых наставить, но этот ряд можно тогда продолжать: Значит, так, приятель, слушай, сюда, внимательно. Это скорее к манере речи, а не к синтаксису.

Comment: Это учебный материал на понимание синтаксиса. Не надо говорить: "Да, я уверен практически на все сто процентов, что во всех приведённых случаях ставятся запятые".  А если только "практически", то надо объяснить теоретически. http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4236878-znachit-tak-nuzhna-li-zapjataja.html  Это тема ответа.  А большинство пользователей оттенков смысла не видят, то есть это упражнение на тему. Полезное упражнение.

Comment: Ну я не говорю, что так быть не может, но тут, мне кажется, дело в другом, а именно в речевой манере произносить слова отдельно. Почему запятая, можно точку тогда поставить? То есть как-будто речь прерывается на полуслове и новая мысль. Если какие-то слова можно обособлять только потому что настроение поменялось, то так можно и каждое слово с новым настроением говорить. А почему все эти слова должны принадлежать одному и тому же предложению? Что такое тогда предложение, как не единство мысли и чувства?

Comment: Это принцип коммуникативности: мы всегда к кому-то обращаемся (к себе, к собеседнику, к читателю, к высшим силам). Просто так ничего не бывает. И везде какой-то смысл, основа всего.  Поэтому все сейчас "перестраивается" на СЕМАНТИКУ: и грамматика, и словари. Принцип, который становится очень важным в современной  лингвистике.

Comment: Как это понимать? Что значит обращаемся всегда?

Comment: В прямом смысле, наша речь всегда адресована кому-то. И мы всегда видим перед собой  этого «собеседника», реального или воображаемого, даже если этот собеседник вы сами. Также у нас всегда есть целевая установка: зачем мы это думаем или говорим. От этого зависит даже стиль нашей речи. Как у Ю. Левитанского:  «Каждый выбирает по себе / слово для любви и для молитвы. / Шпагу для дуэли, меч для битвы / каждый выбирает по себе».

Comment: Можно видеть собеседника, если ты собеседник, но это не обязательно. Тем более собеседника можно представлять и общаться с человеком с позиции этого представления, а можно общаться с человеком непосредственно, минуя представление. Кстати, если вы обратили внимание, то в той книжечке по риторике, есть упражнение "описание". Так вот, описание это восприятие как раз через видимое и ощущаемое, а не через представляемое. В этом смысле риторику бы в школу вернуть и давать детям хотя бы в часть тех упражнений. А их наоборот учат видеть не предметы, не плоть человека - реального, а видеть символику.

Comment: Это не стул, это школьный стул, это не обувь, это сменная обувь, это не одежда, это школьная форма. Каждый предмет соотносится с неким эталоном, некой картинкой, и это психологические моменты связанные с долженствованием. Это не твоя мама - это твой педагог), это не твои друзья, братья - а одноклассники. И дети по сути не научаются различать реальное и представляемое, ну и воображать не учатся само собой. Они постоянно должны быть в роли и воспринимать не вещи сами по себе, а оценивать через уже знание - в этом и кроется подвох, знание не познается, а мир воспринимается через форму знания.

Comment: Вот это прилагательное - это и есть семантика и предикация. И ребенок научается видеть не саму вещь, не суть вещи, не её душу, а её форму - признак. Мир через границы условий - условные туннели. Это и есть суть школы. Школа не учит воспринимать мир целиком и со стороны. Плюс система оценивания деятельности. А это вообще прямое воздействие на рептильный мозг) Ствол мозга, лимбическая система, связана с базовыми рефлексами вроде страх, агрессия, размножение, доминантность и тп. И вот по ней бьет система оценок.

Comment: Рептилоиды, кстати, это не столько прикол и мем, а рептилоиды - это люди у которых работает ствол мозга, то есть базовые рефлексы, вместо неокортекса - высшей нервной деятельности отвечающей за мышление. Левитанского знаю этот стих, думал про него, в нём есть вопрос, а что такое "себе" как это "по себе", откуда это "себе" берется? И в нем прямо много символики.

Comment: "Дьяволу служить или пророку —
каждый выбирает для себя." А кому служат пророки или дьяволы(?)? Ну дьяволы может не люди или нелюди, а пророки-человеки? Имеют ли они выбор кому служить?

Comment: Ну вот... Раньше я Левитанского "целиком" воспринимала, а теперь что? Буду тоже думать: что значит "для себя", а это что значит? Так вся магия поэзии исчезнет.

Comment: Да, это именно магия. А метафизика, метафора - это не магия, в ней нет вымысла, есть только тымысел). В этом разница.

Comment: "Означает так" — это как? Так не говорят, говорят "означает это".

Comment: Короче, второй вариант (смысловой), увы, неверный.

Comment: @oleedd
 Здесь нельзя писать критику. Пожалуйста, оформите свое мнение в поле ответа.

Comment: Здесь можно и нужно писать критику! Это разрешено в правилах сайта. А вот ответ чисто для критики — это совсем не по правилам. Ну так защититесь. Объясните, что такое "означает так". Если сказуемое, то можно добавить "это" (как факт). Тогда: *Это значит так, объясняю в десятый раз.* Неверно. Отсутствие лайков подтверждает. Неверные ответы лучше удалять. Предложите что-то другое.

Comment: Удалять я не буду на этот раз. Политика!   Ваше мнение всего лишь ваше, не более того. Так что ставьте минус по правилам сайта.  Слова "означает так" в примерах нет, это всего лишь пояснение значения глагола.  И встречный вопрос: вы мой персональный КРИТИК? (Тоже  своего рода реклама.)  Здесь нет других "неправильных" ответов, только мои надо удалять? И на этом до свидания, мешаете работать.

Comment: *Слово "значит" в разговорном стиле заменяет фразу "это значит вот что"* — сделайте, чтобы подставлялось (вы с таким же успехом можете написать, что оно слово "слон" заменяет)! Вы так не сможете сделать, потому что это неверно. Там сказуемое не подходит.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148560/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: "Означает/значит так" не равно "означает/значит вот что", это разные вещи! "Так" — это об образе действия, а не о предмете (*вот что*), стыдно не знать. То есть каким образом оно значит, что абсурдно, не получается придумать ситуацию под это. Вот ваш абсурдный вариант: *Оно значит так* (просто добавляем подлежащее). А с вашим "вот что", кстати, получается без проблем: *Оно значит вот что.* Пора удалить неверный ответ. Зачем пачкать сайт? Просто гарантирую вам, что это неверно. Хочется верить, что вы ещё можете открыть уши. Пару лет назад вы меня слышали, а потом будто оглохли (разруш. дружбу).

Comment: Спасибо за остальные комментарии, они меня позабавили, особенно в связи с одной интересной темой из СМИ. (Но озвучивать не буду.)  А вот этот комментарий рекомендую вам УДАЛИТЬ, переход на личности и дискредитация сайта. Не надо его ПАЧКАТЬ, что о нас люди подумают. И что мне делать с вашими ГАРАНТИЯМИ?  Нужен гарантийный талон!  https://lexicography.online/etymology/г/гарантия  С друзьями так не разговаривают:  друзей любят, с ними говорят деликатно.  Меня критикуют в основном враги, хотя и друзья тоже. Всё слушаю!  И всем спасибо говорю, если критика по делу (вслух говорю или про себя).

Comment: Надо не только слушать, но и слышать. Друзей слышат и реагируют на сказанное, а вы разучились. Смотрите разницу и не тупите: *говорю так* (как именно говорю); *говорю вот что*. То же самое и там. Не надо из "как именно" (*так*) делать "что именно". Это неверно. Значение местоимения от замены глагола не меняется. Чтобы вы знали: надо или опровергать критику, или соглашаться с ней. Как бы пропускать мимо ушей — это огромное неуважение к человеку, способное разрушить любую дружбу. Ни разу не видел, чтобы вы были благодарны за критику (не возмущались). Дополнение к ответу — это не критика.

Answer (score 0):

Во всех предложениях нужны запятые.

[«Грамота.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=289683):

[image: рппи рипни]